# How to get longitude, latitude and altitude of clicked point on a placemark?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I'm using google earth plugin api to create and show placemarks to users.

Exampale code of creating and show placemark:

```
function createPlacemark(){
    var polygonPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('Polygon');
    var polygon = ge.createPolygon('');
    polygon.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);
    polygonPlacemark.setGeometry(polygon);
    var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
    polygon.setOuterBoundary(outer);

    var coords = outer.getCoordinates();
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1200); 
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1200); 
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1000); 
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1000); 
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(polygonPlacemark);
    }
```

Now i need to know whether user has clicked the placemark (i do it with event listener) and what the longitude, latitude and altitude of the point in the placemark he clicked.

The problem is that google earth returns the values of the "click" event on the earth surface instead of on the clicked placemark. In some cases the polygon is not lay on the earth (as in the exampale code) and the values are not appropriate.

I have tried to find a  way to get the position of the balloon that opened when placemark is clicked, but with no success.

Is there a way to get that values?

**Edit:**
I'm using somthing similar to the following simplified code :

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            var ge;
            google.load("earth", "1");

            function init() {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
            }

            function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
            }

            function failureCB(errorCode) {
            }


           google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

           function createPlacemark(){
                 var polygonPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('Polygon');
                 var polygon = ge.createPolygon('');
                 polygon.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);
                 polygonPlacemark.setGeometry(polygon);
                 var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
                 polygon.setOuterBoundary(outer);
                 polygonPlacemark.setDescription('test');
                 var coords = outer.getCoordinates();
                         coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1200); 
                 coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.35,33.3544921875,1200); 
                 coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.35,33.3544921875,1000); 
                 coords.pushLatLngAlt(35.3,33.3544921875,1000); 
                 ge.getFeatures().appendChild(polygonPlacemark);

                    lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
                lookAt.setLatitude(35.33); 
                lookAt.setLongitude(33.3544921875);  
                lookAt.setRange(4500);  
                lookAt.setTilt(45); 
                lookAt.setHeading(90);

                   // Update the view in Google Earth 
               ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
               google.earth.addEventListener(polygonPlacemark , 'click', doEvent);
    }

          function doEvent(event) {
            document.getElementById("alt").value=event.getAltitude();
            document.getElementById("lon").value=event.getLongitude();
            document.getElementById("lat").value=event.getLatitude();       
      }

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
           <div id="map3d" style="height: 820px; width: 1680px;"></div>
           <button id="bCreatePlacemark" type="button" onclick="createPlacemark()">Create Placemark</button><br>
           <input id="lon" /><br>
           <input id="lat" /><br>
           <input id="alt" />


     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you attach your event handler, but it sounds like you have attached it to the GEGlobe or GEWindow object rather than the KmlPlacemarks.

To attach an event listener to the specific placemark you would do something like so.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(polygonPlacemark , 'click', doSomething);
function doSomething(event) {
  var lat = event.getTarget().getGeometry().getLatitude();
  var lng = event.getTarget().getGeometry().getLongitude();
  // do something with lat, lng
}
```

If you want to create a 'catch all' event handler that handles click events on all placemarks you can do it using the `GEGlobe` object then using conditional logic to screen for placemark objects.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', doSomething);
function doSomething(event) {
  if (event.getTarget().getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') { //check the event target
    var lat = event.getTarget().getGeometry().getLatitude();
    var lng = event.getTarget().getGeometry().getLongitude();
    // do something with lat, lng
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to attach the click event to the `polygon` itself, then extract the position that event took place. If so this should work.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(polygon , 'click', doSomething);
function doSomething(event) {
  var lat = event.getLatitude();
  var lng = event.getLongitude();
  var alt = event.getaltitude();
  // do something with lat, lng, alt
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's not work for me. `event.getTarget().getGeometry().get...();` not returns values (i have tried yours two suggestions). When i replace it with `event.getLongitude();` it returns values but, of course, this not what i'm search for.

Comment: Please note that I need the point IN the placemark, not the coordinates of the placemark itself. In other words, I need the point which the balloon is appear from.

Comment: Then just use the conditional logic for the placemark, but then use event.getLongitude() and getLatitude() to get the position of the click. That way the click event will only fire when on a placemark but you will get the coordinates of the actual click, rather than the coordinates of the placemark.

Comment: But then the values are on the earth surface rather than on the placemark. the click "pass through" the placemark and I get the values of the point on the earth surface behind the placemark.

Comment: Thankes a lot for your efforts. However it still gives me the coordinates of the point where the click hit the surface rather than where it hit the polygon. As an example to desirable behaviour you can see what happens when you point 3d building from buildings layer (in the Google Earth client)- the coordinates and altitude that appear at the status bar are the coordinates of the wall you point, not the coordinates of the surface behind the building.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean - the click event should be on the surface of the polygon. Please show your actual code - how you attach the event hander, etc. You are probably just making a mistake.

Comment: BTW: When I mentioned "surface" I meant "earth surface". BTW2: i'm using version 6.2.